# What is .git folder and can I delete it?

Tags: git

I used DaisyDisk to get info about my drive. I found a folder named ".git" in my documents. Its size is about 15 GB. what is it? and can I delete it?

Comment: Wat is the full directory name of the .git folder?

Comment: ~/Documents/.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Git](http://git-scm.com) is a version control system and stores the history in a subdirectory .git

That is a way of keeping copies of snapshots source code or other documents in a way so that you can go to the complete set of documents at an earlier given time and/or see when and who changed a file and what change was made.

A version control system can be used just for your documents or put in a shared place so people who collaborate all can see and make changes.

You can use tools like [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) to view what is in your history.

Thus is you are not using git you can delete the .git directory but I would ask how did it get there. It is possible that another application could use git, I would see if any of your apps say they keep old copies of data however I would hope that they would not do this for all of ~/Documents as this would mess up other peoples' use of this directory. The actual directory .git is in would help to identify the application using it.

Comment: I previously installed Github on my mac but didn't use it.
Thanks for answer.